# creating bootstrap modals for dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Created a JavaScript function to dynamically create and append buttons. And call it in a button **"+Add New Cube"**. 
On click of that button **(+Add New Cube)** it dynamically create buttons. 
On click of that dynamically created button,i want a modal OR a div to be displayed. 
I refer a tutorial which generates popups but it seems not helping. can anyone help.

```js
 var num = 1;
    function myFunction() {
      var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      btn.innerHTML = "Cube "+num;
      btn.className = "sam";
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
      btn.onclick = function () {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
    }
      num++;
    }
```

```css
   .sam{
        height:150px;
        width:100px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class = "btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">+ Add New Cubicle</button><br/>
```

Comment: you have to use `$("#myModal").modal("show");` function on the `btn.click`

Comment: @S.Hettz I have added the snippet in the post, in case of still required any changes please do let me know. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this snippet.

```js
var num = 1;
    function myFunction() {
      var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      btn.innerHTML = "Cube "+num;
      btn.className = "sam";
      btn.setAttribute("data-target","#myModal");
      btn.setAttribute("data-toggle","modal");
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
      btn.onclick = function () {
        //alert(this.innerHTML);
         $("#myModal .customMsg").html("Msg for "+ this.innerHTML);
         $("#myModal .modal-title").html(this.innerHTML)

      }

      num++;
   }
```

```css
.sam{
    height:150px;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<button class = "btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">+ Add New Cubicle</button> 

 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body customMsg">
          <p>This is a small modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*UPDATE*

added code to set body dynamically of modal popup

Comment: Thank you!,  this is good to start up but the button text should come as the modal title when we click a button

Comment: Updated the snippet, might be helpful

Comment: yes, this help is the what i exactly wanted, thumbs-up

Answer (score 2):

See this example with the snippet, right now single/common modal popup is defined, you can make it dynamic as per your preference. Hope it helps you!!!

```js
var num = 1;

function openModal(currentObj) {
  $("#myModal").find(".modal-title").text("Cube " + $(currentObj).attr("id"));
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
}

function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = "Cube " + num;
  btn.className = "sam";
  btn.id = num;
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  btn.onclick = function() {
    openModal(this);
  }
  num++
}
```

```css
.sam {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">+ Add New Cubicle</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @ankitkanojia , for sure this helped. can i customized the model like, button text is there as the modal title. Is it possible ?

Comment: @S.Hettz I have made few changes please refer updated post, I have passed the button name as the modal title.